# Correlation between two explanatory variables

Tags: correlation, independence, multicollinearity

I have a multiple regression. Two of my  independent variables are "Repeated Partnerships" and "Company size". When adding the explanatory variable "Company size" to the regression it is statistically significant but it causes the "Repeated partnerships" which was significant before to become insignificant. It is important to note that the correlation between them is relatively low.

When I presented these findings to my advisor he noted that there is not a multicollinearity problem in the specification, but there is a correlation issue in a way that "Company size" affects "Repeated partnerships" but not vice versa.

I would appreciate an extension to his answer, sharpening the difference between collinearity and correlation. And is this situation problematic in any sense?

Comment: Can you post the data? Have you inspected a scatterplot matrix?

Comment: Considering that correlations are symmetric your advisor's comment seems strange.

Comment: How can I add a file?

Comment: The correlation coefficient between those two variable is  0.284482

Comment: Can I refer to `Company size` as moderating variable, in statistical terms?